# Toda pergunta com query deveria ter a tag sql?

Tags: debate, tags

Sempre que respondo perguntas relativas a bancos de dados, tento identificar o banco e quando não há tag correspondente adiciono, e vejo que muita gente da comunidade tem a mesma atitude.

Porém, notei várias perguntas que tem uma *query* no corpo, e apesar de estarem marcadas com a tag do banco correto, como `mysql` ou `sql-server`, não possuem a tag `sql`, e nesse caso passam em branco pela maioria das pessoas que costumam editar, esse caso por exemplo:

[Parametros para consulta em query no sql server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/335452/57220)

Seria uma boa prática geral, sempre que houver uma *query* na pergunta ou resposta, adicionar a tag `sql`?

Pergunto porque entendo que, se uma pergunta tem por exemplo somente a tag `sql-server`, remete à ideia de que é uma pergunta específica **sobre o banco de dados SQL Server**, coisas como instalação, *tunning*, etc, e que não tem relação com uma *query*, ainda que específica para esse banco.

Comment: Ótima pergunta, usar a tag do banco específico já seria suficiente para alguém entender que a questão é sobre SQL, porém colocar a tag `sql` ajuda no filtro. Uma dica, ao meu ver, esse título talvez generalize de mais a pergunta, `query`s não estão limitadas apenas ao bancos SQL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nunca diga nunca, mas eu acho que deveria sim.

Colocá-la chama a sub-comunidade específica. Se eu gosto de ver coisas de SQL mas não outras mais específicas eu não será alertado ou não despertará meu interesse em responder.

Também é interessante na hora de fazer alguma busca e usar um filtro pela *tag*, se não tiver ela provavelmente ficará de fora do resultados e é possível que seja indevidamente.

Em geral a edição de *tags* é mal usada. Eu fazia muito no começo, mas cansei de enxugar gelo. OS usuários novatos ou mesmo experientes não ligam, não gostam e até não querem fazer certo, e os usuários que gostam das coisas certas cansam um pouco arrumar tudo (sem contar que muito também não entendem o sistema de *tags*, alguns até discordam de como elas funcionam). Eu tenho arrumado só o que eu respondo e muito raro alguma coisa muito absurda. Mas incentivo as pessoas fazerem o melhor possível.

Hoje eu acho que deveria existir *supertags* obrigatórias, como tem no meta e SQL seria uma delas. Mas isso não vai mudar. Outras coisa é que talvez deveria ter um sistema hierárquico (mais polêmico), mas também não mudará.

Comment: *"Colocá-la chama a sub-comunidade específica"* perfeito, é exatamente isso. Nem sempre o título da pergunta é claro, e por exemplo se aparece apenas uma tag `postgre`, que é um banco que não domino bem, posso acabar nem entrando na pergunta e perdendo a chance de ajudar, sendo que a pergunta pode se sobre uma query genérica, acredito que aconteça com outra pessoas também

Comment: Sobre a edição de tags, vejo muitos usuários novos fazendo mais que os usuários mais antigos, provavelmente em busca de pontuação.

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim, e por sinal mal feito por não entenderem o sistema. Mas também é culpe do sistema que não tenta ser um mecanismo de ensino. Pra falar a verdade o SO se tornou uma coisa antiga da internet, precisa reformular, precisa ser mais ativo no processo de evolução das pessoas.

Comment: compartilho de várias críticas que vc faz ao sistema do SO, acho que cresceu absurdamente rápido e não deram a atenção devida a vários detalhes, por é importante comentar e apontar, acho que aquele sistema de "assistente" na pergunta já é um bom passo