# Tags não devem ser usadas para ajudar a formatar melhor uma discussão (pergunta e respostas)?

Tags: debate, tags

Eu acabei de ver essa pergunta do **Ricardo Pontual**:

> [Toda pergunta com query deveria ter a tag sql?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7379/86952)

e ela me lembrou de uma dúvida que me surgiu outro dia: Devemos usar alguma tag pelo simples objetivo de melhorar a formatação do código na pergunta e respostas de uma discussão?

Digo isso porque tenho respondido muitas perguntas sobre o eSocial (webservice do governo federal brasileiro, que visa obrigar que todos os empregadores enviem informações de folha de pagamento mensalmente para eles), e, com muita frequência essas perguntas têm algum trecho de linguagem, como C# por exemplo, mas muitas vezes também têm algum trecho de XML.

Só que, quando a pergunta/resposta têm um trecho de XML, mas a tag `xml` não foi usada na pergunta, o trecho de XML não é formatado usando a regra de formatação para XML do SO, que facilita a visualização do XML, por marcar as tags do XML com cores diferentes. Então, nesses casos eu sempre edito a pergunta para inserir a tag `xml`.

Entretanto, outro dia eu fiz isso (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/186847), e acrescentei o comentário:

> *Acrescentei a tag 'xml' para que o código de XML na pergunta e nas respostas fique corretamente formatado.*

Mas um dos revisores rejeitou a minha edição, e comentou o seguinte:

> *Esta edição adiciona tags que não ajudam a definir o assunto da pergunta. As tags devem ajudar a descrever sobre o que se trata a pergunta, e não somente o que ela contém.*

Então surgiu a dúvida, esse tipo de procedimento que eu estou adotando está errado?

Comment: Você pode tentar isso: [Destaque da sintaxe para o código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Na minha humilde opinião não seria uma duplicata porque a pergunta que você mencionou questiona porque o recurso **syntax highlight** não funciona no SOpt como no SOen, e a minha pergunta é sobre se o uso de tag com intuito de formatação é certo ou não. O recurso de *syntax highlight* responde parte da minha dúvida, mas as perguntas não são iguais, e, assim como eu nunca tinha ouvido falar desse recurso aqui no SO, outros "novatos" podem chegar com a mesma dúvida, e não vão pesquisar esse termo, porque nem o conhecem. Mas posso estar enganado, vocês conhecem as regras mais a fundo do que eu!

Comment: De fato a discussão sobre adicionar a tag é válida. Quanto às informações de *syntax highlight* ela consta sim na página de ajuda do editor, tal como citei no primeiro comentário.

Comment: Verdade... eu nunca tinha reparado naquele botão de Ajuda no canto do editor, e provavelmente dificilmente entraria no link 'Ajuda avançada', mas, realmente está lá, obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro: não fazemos discussões aqui, por ser uma site de Q&A fazemos perguntas e damos respostas.

Segundo: *tags* não formatam nada, elas classificam conteúdo e permitem que sejam melhor buscadas em futuro. Seja aqui no site seja por um buscador. *Tag* correta ajuda muito no SEO.

Mas indo ao ponto dito algumas *tags* tem um mecanismo de estilos, o chamado *syntax highlighter* para ajudar na visualização. Quando a postagem tem a *tag* ela é usada. Caso não tenha a *tag*, mas provavelmente deveria, ou se tem códigos de diferentes linguagens no mesmo *post* e ele se perder pode marcar manualmente o trecho com qual *highlighter* usar. Veja mais em [Podemos ter Syntax Highlight nos códigos como no SO?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/33/101).

Eu acho que erraram ao rejeitar, e quem aceitou no final poderia ter "Melhorado" em vez de "Editado", o que daria a edição para você. Então você fez o certo porque o problema é sobre XML, não é só um acaso ter um XML ali.

Comment: Eu usei o termo "discussão" para representar a dupla pergunta/resposta, mas, não está correto mesmo, obrigado pela correção. Sobre a explicação, entendi e obrigado pela resposta. Mas, ainda restou uma dúvida, se as tags "classificam conteúdo", e a pergunta contém XML, não está certo de qualquer forma usar a tag `xml`?

Comment: Você já respondeu, não tinha visto a edição, obrigado!

Comment: Esqueci de comentar que não conhecia sobre o recurso de **syntax highlight**. Esse recurso não está acessível no menu de opções de edição de resposta, não é? Seria interessante que aparecesse lá de alguma forma, senão fica muito escondido e as pessoas com menos conhecimento ficam sem saber que a opção existe...

Comment: É, tem um monte de coisa que poderiam melhorar, mas já foi tantas vezes pedido, nem temos esperanças mais.